# Number input from txt file. Weird glitch C++

Tags: c++, arrays, text, input, struct

This is for homework and i've developed most of it on my own already.
I just keep getting a weird glitch. In the input file below i am supposed to take the name and numbers and put them into 6 different variables. the name into a string the numbers into arrays and the last two numbers into ints.

When i run my program and want to grab the tenth number for any of the strings it presents me with the next one over eg. want 94 get 15 in Alice's grades.

here's the file and here is the code please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

//all of a students info is stored here
struct Student {
    string name;
    int asgn[9];
    int quiz[9];
    int lab[9];
    int midterm;
    int final;

};
Student s[22];







int main(){

    string str;
    ifstream in;


    in.open("C:/CS161Grades.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++){
        getline(in, str);
        stringstream ss(str);
        ss >> s[i].name >> s[i].asgn[0] >> s[i].asgn[1] >> s[i].asgn[2] >> s[i].asgn[3] >> s[i].asgn[4] >> s[i].asgn[5] >> s[i].asgn[6] >> s[i].asgn[7] >> s[i].asgn[8] >> s[i].asgn[9]
            >> s[i].quiz[0] >> s[i].quiz[1] >> s[i].quiz[2] >> s[i].quiz[3] >> s[i].quiz[4] >> s[i].quiz[5] >> s[i].quiz[6] >> s[i].quiz[7] >> s[i].quiz[8] >> s[i].quiz[9]
            >> s[i].lab[0] >> s[i].lab[1] >> s[i].lab[2] >> s[i].lab[3] >> s[i].lab[4] >> s[i].lab[5] >> s[i].lab[6] >> s[i].lab[7] >> s[i].lab[8] >> s[i].lab[9]
            >> s[i].midterm
            >> s[i].final;

        cout << s[2].name << s[2].lab[9] << endl;
    }







//pause and stop
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The file is formatted as such with twenty students

```
  Name     Assignments                      Quizzes                          Labs                              MidT  Final

    Alice    71 97 64 30 99 54  8 88 92 94    15 55 91 37 71  1  5 52 37 46     6 19 17 68  7 97 36 31 33 10     72    46
```

Comment: The input line is way too long man, it's awful. Why don't you loop ???

Answer (score 0):

1 - Not only the `int asgn[9];` array but also `int quiz[9];` and `int lab[9];` arrays can contain only 9 element. But you are trying to read 10 for each array. Try replacing your struct with:

```
struct Student {
string name;
int asgn[10];
int quiz[10];
int lab[10];
int midterm;
int final;

};
```

or alternatively you may use std::vector if you want your list size to be flexible.

2 - The text file snippet that you posted seem to have titles at the first line. So you may want to read them first and then start reading the data starting from the second line with a while loop. This is more flexible than `for` loop because later you may need to read more student data. With `for` loop you will have to modify the loop boundaries whereas with `while` loop that won`t be necessary:

```
getline(in, str); // str has the titles if you need them
...
while (getline(in, str)) // Now you are reading the data line by line
{
    // Your code to process str goes here
}
```

Comment: Thank you all that was extremely helpful i thought that it was like 0 - 9 and the means ten variables thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
int asgn[9];
```

That's room enough for *nine* numbers (`asgn[0]` through `asgn[8]`), but you're trying to store *ten* in it. Your assignment to `asgn[9]` writes past the end of the array, which is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I fixed your code, basically the problem is that you're confused about the size of the array and the fact that it's 0 indexed. You have 10 elements per array so you need to declare your table as `int arr[10]` and not 9. However when you reference it, arr[9] is the 10th element. Got it? :)

I implemented a shortcut for this awful line, it could be even cleaner but I did not want to butcher your code too much and let you think about it by yourself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

#define AR_SIZE 10

//all of a students info is stored here
struct Student {
    string name;
    int asgn[AR_SIZE];
    int quiz[AR_SIZE];
    int lab[AR_SIZE];
    int midterm;
    int final;

};
Student s[22];


void fill_array(int *arr, stringstream &ss) {
    for (int idx = 0; idx < AR_SIZE; idx++) {
            ss >> arr[idx];
            cout << arr[idx] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

int main(){

    string str;
    ifstream in;


    in.open("test.txt");

    for (int i = 0; getline(in, str); i++) {

        stringstream ss(str);
        ss >> s[i].name;

        fill_array(s[i].asgn, ss);
        fill_array(s[i].quiz, ss);
        fill_array(s[i].lab, ss);

        ss >> s[i].midterm >> s[i].final;

        cout << s[2].name << s[2].lab[9] << endl;
    }


//pause and stop
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```